# Learning data.table - how to update values by row number and column name

Tags: r, data.table

My last few posts have been written poorly, so I will attempt to do a better and cleaner job this time.

I am learning how to work with the data tables object, and one task I am struggling with is updating values in the data table by both row number and column name at the same time. With data.frames this is much easier and I just do the following:

```
my_df = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = (100)))
names(my_df) = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5")
head(my_df)

  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

replacement = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
my_df[2, names(my_df)[1:5]] = replacement
head(my_df)

  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

so, fairly easy with a dataframe. however, I am struggling with this same exact task with a datatable. using the same structure for an example data table as i did with the dataframe above, i've tried the following:

```
my_dt = data.table(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = (100)))
names(my_dt) = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5")
head(my_dt)

   P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
1: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

replacement = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# my_dt[i == 2, names(my_dt)[1:5]] = replacement
# my_dt[i == 2, names(my_dt)[1:5] := replacement]  
# my_dt[2, names(my_dt)[1:5]] = replacement
# my_dt[2, names(my_dt)[1:5] := replacement]
```

however none of the four commented lines did the correct substitution. appreciate any help!

Thanks, 
Canovice

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but how about writing your stuff into a data frame and then converting it to a data table?

Comment: i want to use data tables to speed up my code, performance is very important for this project. I frequently have to access subsets of this df / dt and update their values, and i thought accessing subsets of a dt was faster than accessing subsets of a df. so that's why i don't want to write into a dataframe

Comment: You shouldn't need this. That you do lets me suspect that you should use a sparse matrix instead of a data.table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you can do this:

```
x <- names(my_dt)[1:5]

my_dt[, (x) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = x]

my_dt[2,  (x):= as.list(replacement)]
```

First we convert the target columns in `my_dt` to `numeric`. `.SDcols` represents the subset of columns in `.SD` that we are interested in. `.SD` holds all the columns in the `data.table` (except the ones used in `by`).

Once we convert the target columns to numeric, we update the values by reference.

**Note**: It is not necessary to define x beforehand, everything can be done on the fly. However, if you define `x`, you need to wrap it in `()` to make sure `data.table` doesn't look for the column `x`

Comment: yes thanks!, I like both this and mkt's solution, but will use yours because it is important that I initialize with NAs and keep track of NAs in my data table. thank you

Comment: Last followup, thanks again. Can I update values by reference over multiple rows at a time? For example, if i wanted to update rows 2:5, columns (x) all with the replacement object?

Yes I can! okay thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Made a couple of small changes to your example, but this works:

```
#Filled data.table with integers instead of NAs to avoid converting 
#from logical later
#Left out names as it wasn't relevant to the example
my_dt = as.data.table(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = (100), 1L))
head(my_dt)

replacement <- 1:5
#Loop through columns and use set to replace values without making a copy
for(k in 1:5) set(my_dt, i = 2L, j = k , value = replacement[k])
head(my_dt)
```

Comment: thanks!. do you think the issue may have been then that I was initializing my dataframe with all NAs?

Comment: No, that was not the only problem. I did that mainly for convenience in my response (it wasn't clear that NAs were important in your example). Your code was also trying to assign all 5 replacement values to each of the row and column elements.